# Visual Studio Hangs in debug?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

For the past couple of days, Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 have been hanging during debug mode. Most of the time, i dont get this issue until further into my project. When i press the `Start` Button, everything continues as normal, but then hangs with this message at the bottom of visual Studio statusBar.

[image]

Inside Task Manager, when i try to force taskkill, or end process/process tree, this continues to stay present in my running processes.

[image]

Even after a reinstall, nothing seems to help it. I did see somewhere on the Microsoft Developer forums where a person was told it was something to do with the windows sybmol server?. What do i need to do to fix this issue i am having?

After this occurs once, i am forced to reboot my computer. Even if i open Visual Studio after this happens, it still has the same issue.

Comment: I see "Express" in the task manager, do these happen to be the express versions?

Comment: @txtechhelp Yes, you are correct. This is the express version. For windows Desktop.

Comment: Do you have the latest updates/service packs for VS and .NET/etc.?

Comment: Actually, i did not install them yet. I will do so then respond back with the results. Also, Even Visual Studio 2012 had this same issue even when i had it updated.

Comment: The latest update for Visual Studio 2013 does not fix this issue.

Comment: exclude the symbol loading for this DLL in the VS options